# pandas sort_values is working outside a for loop, but not inside?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a for loop that will take a dataframe with census data, count the populations of the three largest counties of each state, and write the sum to a new series. Here is the function that is not working:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

##created a dataframe earlier with a census csv file called 'census_df'


def bad_function():
    only_counties = census_df.set_index(['STNAME'])

    ser = pd.Series(index = only_counties.index)
    ser = ser.index.drop_duplicates() ##get a unique list of all 50 states from the dataframe

    state_name = pd.Series(index = ser)


    for i in state_name.index:
        a = only_counties.loc[i, 'CENSUS2010POP']
        a = a.sort_values(ascending=False)

        population = np.sum(a[0:3])

        state_name.loc[i] = population

    return state_name
```

When I call this function, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-dc2686648261> in <module>()
     26     return state_name
     27 
---> 28 answer_six()

<ipython-input-59-dc2686648261> in answer_six()
     18     for i in state_name.index:
     19         a = only_counties.loc[i, 'CENSUS2010POP']
---> 20         a = a.sort_values(ascending=False)
     21 
     22         population = np.sum(a[0:3])

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'sort_values'
```

HOWEVER, when I ditched the loop for testing purposes and selected one item('Alabama') from the index of what I am trying to iterate over, and use the same sort_values method in the same way, it works just fine. Like this:

```
def bad_function():
    only_counties = census_df.set_index(['STNAME'])

    ser = pd.Series(index = only_counties.index)
    ser = ser.index.drop_duplicates()

    state_name = pd.Series(index = ser)

    a = only_counties.loc['Alabama', 'CENSUS2010POP']
    a = a.sort_values(ascending=False)

    b = np.sum(a[0:3])

    return a, b
```

It returns exactly what I want, which is a: a list of counties in the state sorted by population and b: the sum of the three highest population counties. So what is happening?

Comment: What does the following print?
`for i in state_name.index:
    print (I)`

Comment: You mean print(i)?    'Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Colorado
Connecticut
Delaware
District of Columbia
Florida
Georgia
Hawaii
Idaho
Illinois
Indiana
Iowa
Kansas
Kentucky
Louisiana
Maine
Maryland
Massachusetts
Michigan
Minnesota
Mississippi
Missouri
Montana
Nebraska
Nevada
New Hampshire
New Jersey
New Mexico
New York
North Carolina
North Dakota
Ohio
Oklahoma
Oregon
Pennsylvania
Rhode Island
South Carolina
South Dakota
Tennessee
Texas
Utah
Vermont
Virginia
Washington
West Virginia
Wisconsin
Wyoming'

Comment: How about you show us your data, and expected output. The reason `sort_values` won't work in the loop is because you're accessing float values, while the function is to be called on a data frame or series.

Comment: Reiterating the comment above, the variable `a = only_counties.loc[i, 'CENSUS2010POP']` is not returning dataframe or series that you can call `sort_values` on. Please print what the value `a` is before calling the `sort_values` on it. I do not think it is a dataframe/series.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the following:

```
for i in state_name.index:
    print (I)
```

prints the state names or index?

Comment: It prints the state names as strings, not the index.

Comment: Reiterating the comment above, the variable `a = only_counties.loc[i, 'CENSUS2010POP']` is not returning dataframe or series that you can call `sort_values` on. Please print what the value `a` is before calling the `sort_values` on it. I do not think it is a dataframe/series.